# Meteor unsubscribe from Collection on Client

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm trying to implement pagination in my app without using external libraries and I'm running into issues. I saw a few other topics on this, but they didn't seem to apply to my use case (or were experiencing different issues altogether). Here's my template.

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> postPreview}}
    <hr>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  {{> spinner}}
{{/if}}

<!-- Pager -->
<ul class="pager">
  {{#if showNewerPostsButton}}
    <li class="previous previousButton">
      <a>&larr; Newer Posts </a>
    </li>
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showOlderPostsButton}}
    <li class="next nextButton">
      <a>Older Posts &rarr;</a>
    </li>
  {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Basically the way it's supposed to work is that when the user clicks one of the buttons, the server is supposed to get the next items in the record set and 'ideally' update the subscription to match. I'm having problems making the subscription record set match what I want: It looks like Meteor keeps collecting records with every new subscription.

```
Template.postsList.events({
  'click .nextButton': (e) => {
    let page = parseInt(FlowRouter.getParam('page'));
    if (page === undefined || isNaN(page)) {
      page = 0;
    }
    FlowRouter.setParams({ page: page + 1 });
  },
  'click .previousButton': (e) => {
    let page = parseInt(FlowRouter.getParam('page'));
    if (page === undefined || isNaN(page) || page < 1) {
      page = 1;
    }

    FlowRouter.setParams({ page: page - 1 });
  },
});
```

Right now, when I click the button, what I'm pretty sure is happening is Meteor is seeing my change to `FlowRouter` params and runs my `template.autorun` (below). My first thought to resolving this problem was to use `Meteor.subscribe()`'s returned `handle` to `handle.stop()` the subscription. Unfortunately, it appears that inside this function, both `this.subscribe()` and `Meteor.subscribe()` don't return an actual handle that can be used to `handle.stop()` the subscription and instead returns a `subscriptionId` string. I don't know how to use this string or if it's even possible to use it.

```
Template.postsList.onCreated(function () {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function () {
    var page = parseInt(FlowRouter.getParam('page'));
    if (page == undefined || page < 0 || isNaN(page)) {
      page = 0;
    }
    var handle = Session.get('postPreviewsHandle');
    if (handle) {
      console.dir(handle);
      handle.stop(); // Error! Function doesn't exist because this is only a string
    }

    // Meteor.subscribe() behaves the same way here
    handle = self.subscribe('postPreviews', page);

    Session.set('postPreviewsHandle', handle);
  });
});
```

Am I doing this right? Any help in pointing me in the right direction for this would be super fantastic -- I've been trying to get pagination working for a couple days now and keep running into hurdles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if session variable can store a `handle` but you can try and add it on template instance (`self`) instead

```
Template.postsList.onCreated(function () {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function () {
    var page = parseInt(FlowRouter.getParam('page'));
    if (page == undefined || page < 0 || isNaN(page)) {
      page = 0;
    }
    var handle = self.handle;
    if (handle) {
      console.dir(handle);
      handle.stop();
    }

    self.handle = self.subscribe('postPreviews', page);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately calling 'subscribe()' AT ALL inside 'autorun()' causes Meteor to return a string. Afaik there's no way to 'stop()' a template level subscription manually because of this.